# array of chars instead of string

Tags: c++

everyone!
I have some problems about strings and array of chars.I'm  writing a  project about database based on B-tree, where keys are some class, something like this:

```
  string name;
  double mark;
  int phone_number;
```

So, I implement the insert function, but at the search function i have some problems , here is the search function:

```
node* btree::search(string x)
{
    node* p = root;
    int i, j;
    j = 0;
    while( p )
    {
        cout << "for iter: " << j << p->noofkeys << endl;
        for( i = 0; i < p->noofkeys; i++ )
            if(x == p->data[i].key.getName() )
                return(p);

        p = p->nextindex(x);
    }
    return NULL;
 }
```

and nextindex:

```
node* node::nextindex(string x)
{
    int i;
    if( x < data[0].key.getName())
       return first;

    for( i=0; i < noofkeys; i++ ) {
      if( x < data[i].key.getName() || x == data[i].key.getName() )
        return data[i-1].next;
    }
    return data[i-1].next;
}
```

I'm not sure but i this the problem is coming from camparing strings, but i don't know why? Is it that they allocate diffrent space in memory and actually are difrrent object? Is it good to use array of chars instead of string ?

Comment: I love how you say there is a problem, and then decide to keep that problem secret. What is the actual problem...?

Comment: when i insert in tree some data , like Studen s("Jonh", 5.30, 2547) and try to search for Jonh :  search("Jonh") ( lets suppose there is btree and btreeNode implementation) it's just returns NULL

Comment: Where is the `char` array in your program?

Comment: If you use a `char` array instead of `std::string`, you can't use `==` to compare them, you need to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Run the program in your favorite debugger, and example both "x" and "node.key.getName()" in this expression: `x == p->data[i].key.getName()`.  But look in the debugger first!!!  ALSO: Consider substituting [std::string.compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).  This will successfully compare a C++ std::string with a C null-terminated character array.  FINALLY: Unlike Java, C++ std::string "==" is overloaded to mean what you think it means...

Comment: @Barmar: Given it's being passed to a function that only accepts `std::string`, the C-style string literal would get converted to a `std::string` anyway.

Comment: Even without a debugger, you can add some logging - e.g. the first thing I'd do in `nextindex` would be `std::cerr << "nextindex('" << s << "') noofkeys " << noofkeys; if (noofkeys) std::cerr << "[0].keyname " << data[0].key.getName(); std::cerr << '\n';` - with your current code, if `noofkeys` is ever 0 you read from an invalid `data` index.  Another way to check such things is to use `data.at(i).xyz...` everywhere and catch/print any exception.

Comment: Your for loop in nextindex should start with 1.  You may be dereferencing -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm guessing the problem might be `x == p->data[i].key.getName()`.  I'd need to know more about your program to be certain.
2. Rather than [Play 20 Questions](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/20-Questions), I strongly encourage you to familiarize yourself with your compiler's debugger and step through your code.  Any time spent learning a debugger is a wise investment, IMHO...
3. Here is an example that illustrates [std::string.compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/):

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
p=abc
p: NOT FOUND
```

SAMPLE CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

class node {
  char m_name[80];
public:
  node(char *name);
  char * getName ();
  node * search(std::string x);
};

node::node(char * name) {
  strcpy (m_name, name);
}

char *
node::getName() {
  return m_name;
}

node *
node::search(std::string x) {
  if (x.compare(getName()) == 0)
    return this;
  else
    return NULL;
}

void print_result(node *p) {
  if (p)
    printf ("p=%s\n", p->getName());
  else
    printf ("p: NOT FOUND\n");
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Create a node object
  node my_node("abc");

  // Search: should match
  node * p = my_node.search("abc");
  print_result(p);

  // Search again: should *not* match
  p = my_node.search("123");
  print_result(p);

  return 0;
}
```

'Hope that helps!